# Android cardview card turns blue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using black and white as background colore of the card but it is turning to a blue tint?
What to do?

I am not using any other color at all.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grCS9.jpg)

Comment: Post your app theme and your layout

Comment: paste your xml code to question

Comment: Solved the issue self , instead of background colour I use imageview to color the card.

Answer (score 0):

With the cardView android:background doesn't work properly.
Instead of this you can use app:cardBackgroundColor for Cardviews.

to change the backgrounds for a cardview app:cardBackgroundColor works fine.

thanks.

Try this..

Comment: I am using app:cardBackgroundColor only.

Answer (score -1):

To change the background color of cardview you can use **card_view:cardBackgroundColor**
Thanks